# Sharepoint 2010 WebPartZone

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

Is it possible to control the output of a webpartzone in sharepoint. 
We would like not to have tables.

What are you doing to handle this ?

Answer (score 0):

We haven't done that. But we did similar stuff to override behavior of other SP controls.

First of all you need to learn the conception of [ASP .NET Control Adapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.adapters.controladapter%28v=VS.90%29.aspx).

The main idea is that it's possible to override behavior of any control. So, in this case you can override Web Part Zone Render method and put your logic there.

The only issue is that you need to register your control adapter for specific browser and use .browser files for that. To workaround that create your own HttpModule and handle BeginRequestEvent. There you can register your adapter for all browsers, e.g.

```
var browser = m_Application.Context.Request.Browser;
if (browser == null)return;
if (!browser.Adapters.Contains(webPartZoneTypeName)){
   browser.Adapter[webPartZoneTypeName] = strongNameOfYourAdapter;
}
```

Hope this will help.